# How to give ID to a nested tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I have a nested tabulator which I created in the following manner :

```
 var Col= row.getCell("column").getElement();
 var SubTd = document.createElement("td");
 Col.appendChild(SubTd);

 var subTable = new Tabulator(SubTd, {
      data:row.getData().Xpaths,
      columns:[{field:"Value",editor: true}]
  })
```

I want to give an ID to 'subTable'. How should I do it? I read the documentation but can't find. 
I am using Version 4.1.

Comment: `SubTd.id = "foo";` …?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a standard DOM node with the line:

```
var SubTd = document.createElement("td");
```

So to set the id you use the ***id*** property on the node:

```
SubTd.id = "whatever-id-you-want-to-use";
```

Though it would generally be considered bad practice to do this if you are adding a sub table for each row in the table as id's should be unique on the page and should not be duplicated.

If you want to do this for styling purposes you would be better of doing this in a class:

```
SubTd.classList.add("your-style");
```